# Would an ARM Processor be the way to go?

Tags: c, operating-system, arm, hardware

I was making a little device that would have three buttons (like the ones at radioshack) and each preform its own action. These buttons and their actions would be controlled by a **very** small real time operating system that I would put on this device.

1. Would I need an ARM Processor in any way?
2. How would I put the real time operating system on the device?
3. What OS would I have to compile this on (ex. Ubuntu? Mac OS X? Windows 7?)?
4. Are there any examples of anyone doing this?

P.S. No prebuilt boards (ex. arduino). I would build the board myself.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I would build the board myself." - how skilled are you at that? And how complex are your requirements? Chances are you can do whatever you need to do with a processor with fewer pins.

Comment: The questions you are asking are hinting that you aren't so familiar with embedded boards. I wouldn't recommend to try to build one yourself when you can't say what chip fits your needs. Also, what are the "3 actions" you are talking about? Depending on the complexity of the actions different chips might be suitable...

Comment: @Rup 1. Honestly I am on a scale of 1(Hey I just made a simple circuit with a battery, two wires, and a lightbulb!) to 10(I just built a half car half speed boat that flys), I am around 4.

Comment: @Coder404: Around 4 is a dangerous place to be; because a lot of people who think they are a 4 are actually a 2, because one of the problems with being a 2 is being unable to tell how far along the scale you actually are.

Comment: ARM would almost certainly be overkill for this - just use a PIC: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/PIC_Microcontroller

Comment: If you dont already know all of these answers very very well then you are not ready to be building your own boards.  go to sparkfun.com, look at arduinos and the msp430 board for $5 and the plethera of ARM solutions (there and elsewhere, $20 buys an impressive microcontroller that I have not seen equalled). http://github.com/dwelch67 I have examples for how to use a number of boards with open source tools, the msp430 and the stm32f4 discovery are two that would stand out as boards to look into.

Comment: question 2 implies you dont know if you even need an rtos, if you had experience with embedded rtoses you would know the answer to that question.  Depending on the actions determines what software, how much, etc.  You might be unecessarily pushing yourself into a $200+ solution when a $2 would do the same job.

Comment: sparkfun.com also has an association with a board shop so that once you are at the point where you are ready to make a board (based on your questions you are a long way away from that personally, if you find a partner with board and bootloader experience you can shorten that learning curve) you can at least investigate that board shop, it appears to be cost friendly.

Answer (score 5):

Even if you don't want to use a prebuilt board in the finished product, I'd recommend getting a prebuilt board (like the Arduino), build your product, program it, test it, etc. while on the breadboard, and then simply rebuild it however you want, using the same hardware as you've been using.

That helps you out especially the next time you're building something, because you already have the prototype board and the toolchain ready to go.

Compiling your files can be done on any OS.

---

Enumerated version:

1. No, and I wouldn't even recommend using an ARM processor; but rather an Atmega328 or similar.
2. Using a programmer.
3. Any.
4. Probably millions, or at least hundreds of thousands of examples, yes.

Comment: About #4 Could you send me a link to some of the examples?

Comment: @Coder404: You are not a 4. Get a pre-made board, with a kit, read up some on [Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/). The place is packed with inspiration, advice, and a few humbling realizations, I'm sure.